# Spark master won't show running application in UI when I use spark-submit for python script

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

[image: <master_IP>:8081] `The image shows 8081 UI.` The master shows running application when I start a scala shell or pyspark shell. But when I use `spark-submit` to run a python script, master doesn't show any running application. This is the command I used: `spark-submit --master spark://localhost:7077 sample_map.py`. The web UI is at :4040. I want to know if I'm doing it the right way for submitting scripts or if spark-submit never really shows running application.

`localhost:8080` or `<master_ip>:8080` doesn't open for me but `<master_ip>:8081` opens. It shows the executor info.

These are my configurations in spark-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=512m 
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=4040
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2 
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/opt/worker
export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=512m
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/tmp/spark  
export SPARK_MASTER_IP 'splunk_dep'
```

I'm using `CentOS` , `python 2.7` and `spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Local run use this:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Your app Name").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

while you do sparkSubmit:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Your app Name")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

This won't work in local test but when you compile with this and spark submit job it will show in UI.

Hope this explains.

Comment: I haven't used that. But I did initialize SparkContext like `sc = SparkContext("local","test")`. If I change it to `sc = SparkContext("localhost","test")`, I  get a parsing error : ` Could not parse Master URL: 'localhost'`

Comment: if you are running on master you dont need to specify any, remove local and run it it will show up.

Comment: `val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Ad Request Metrics").setMaster("local")` use this, here for test purpose use`.setMaster("local")`. but when ever you are running in master remove that

Comment: Updated my answer check that out

Comment: I'm using python. So i tried `sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test")  sc = SparkContext(sparkConf)`  and  I'm getting invalid syntax for `SaprkConf()`. Have I written it right?

Comment: Thank you so much! After so much struggle got it right. In pyspark I defined it like this: `sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("test")  sc = SparkContext(conf=sparkConf)`. Now the UI is showing me the running application.

Answer (score 3):

You can open spark master’s web UI, which is http://localhost:8080 by default to see running apps (in standalone cluster mode) :[image: Spark Master UI]

If multiple apps are running - they will bind to port 4040, 4041, 4042 ...

> You can access this interface by simply opening http://:4040 in a web browser. If multiple SparkContexts are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc).

Comment: Yes. But the same doesn't work only for spark-submit using a python script. The pic that you've shown is for the scala shell right? Scala shell works for me also on 4040.

Comment: It does. I've ran ./bin/spark-submit --master spark://node7:7077 examples/src/main/python/pi.py 1000 and it did showup in UI on 4040 and in completed apps in 8080. Are you sure spark-master is running? Try ./sbin/start-all.sh

Comment: Did you run spark shell in local mode or standalone cluster? Here is documentation on how to setup standalone cluster mode http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

Comment: @kaks What does 8081 say Master URL is?

Comment: I've attached the image in the question.

Comment: And I've done the clustering in standalone mode I assume because that was the doc that i followed. The spark UI shows that the master is still ALIVE. Could you tell me what is `1000` you've mentioned in your spark-submit command?

Comment: That is an argument for pi.py. Can you run this: ./bin/spark-submit --master spark://splunk_dep:7077 sample_map.py

Comment: That also doesn't work for me. I don't get it. It works for pyspark and scala shell but not spark-submit.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that the port is on 4041, not 4040

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing SPARK-UI when the application is running or after it completed its execution?

Try adding some code, which will wait for key-press (hence the spark execution won't end) - and see if it solve your problem.

Comment: I keep refreshing UI while the script is running and after it has completed. But still it doesn't show. I tried adding user input in between, even then there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

You just go to localhost:8080 and check that there is one completed application which you submit.

Comment: It doesn't show any completed application in 4040 for the spark-submit alone. For me 8080 is not reachable.